# InternetOpenUrl exception thrown (Kernelbase.dll) - Unknown interface

Tags: c++

I'm using this code to read some text from a site:

```
HINTERNET hInternet, hFile;
DWORD rSize;
char buffer[30] = "\0";

hInternet = InternetOpenW(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
hFile = InternetOpenUrlW(hInternet, L"http://google.com", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

InternetReadFile(hFile, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &rSize);
```

And this gets displayed in the Debug window at the InternetOpenUrl line

> Exception thrown at 0x75BFC42D (KernelBase.dll) in testnowindow.exe: 0x800706B5: Interface Unknown

The code runs fine and the exception is handled internally since i don't get a debugger break, can i ignore this safely? I've tried both compiling as x86 and x64 in debug mode and it always happens. 
I'm running windows 7 64-bit.